# Fetch not returning data

Tags: javascript

Javascript:

```
fetch("https://localhost/data.php", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    data1: data1,
    data2: data2
  })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => function (json) {
  console.log("Successful fetch.");
  console.log(json);
})
.catch((error) => function (error) {
  console.log("Failed to fetch. " + error);
});
```

data.php:

```
<?php
echo '{
    "reply": true
}';
?>
```

I am trying to use a post request with fetch, but I cannot get a reply back from my PHP file, but I can access it from my browser.

Comment: what output do you see in the browser developer tools console? how do you `access it from my browser.` since it's a POST request?

Comment: The developer console says "Fetching..."

Comment: Why would it say that? You don't output that

Comment: Oh, I have the fetch in a function, and to make sure that the function is running, I added a `console.log` with that in it, I just forgot to include it.

Comment: The PHP file is above, but before I can even get any post data sent, I cant even get a normal  reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this line `.then(json => function (json) {`. This code asking the `then`'s callback function to return another function

```
fetch("https://localhost/data.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data1: data1,
      data2: data2
    })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log("Successful fetch.");
    console.log(json);
  })
```

Comment: alternatively - remove the `json =>` :p